# WPF: Validation of multiple textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

[image]

Here's the situation:

I've got 3 textboxes where one put First Name, Last Name and Age respectively. Label with big red "!" shall be only visible when:

**Any** of the textboxes has no content **OR** Age (third textbox) is a negative number **OR** Age is bigger than int.MaxValue.

I already got two validation rules (one for first/last name and another for age). What do I do now? Do I need some kind of converter that checks all three input fields and returns true/false? How to implement this in XAML?

Comment: Are you using MVVM or just doing this in the code behind?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) to validate the fields - see [this article](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/) which explains how to use it. You'll just need to adapt it to have one field displaying errors instead of individual ones for all three.